# Python estimates

Tags: python, estimation

I am trying to write a `Python` code where the user gives a number and the number of decimals it wants to be rounded to. Then the program returns the first number in scientific notation.

My code:

```
def csign(a,b):   
   #a=number,b=decimals
   a=float(a)
   b=float(b)
   return "{:.b e}".format(a)
```

The desired functionality should work like:

```
input: csign(123456,3)
output: 1.23 e5
```

But I get an error saying

```
Format specifier missing precision.
```

Is there any way I could make the program recognize `b` as a precision?

Answer (score 2):

You can nest format specifiers:

```
return '{:.{}e}'.format(a, b)
```